# LibGDX build failed to apply plugin [id 'org.gradle.idea']

Tags: java, gradle, build, libgdx

I've downloaded the LibGDX setup app and when trying to build a project with IDEA plugin support i got:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'idea' not found in root project 'Game'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I've added an init.gradle with `apply plugin: 'idea'` to C:\Users\user.gradle to activate the IDEA plugin and now i'm getting:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script 'C:\Users\user\.gradle\init.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating initialization script.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.gradle.idea']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'IdeaPlugin'.
      > Unable to determine constructor argument #3: missing parameter of interface org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.IdeArtifactRegistry, or no service of type interface org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.IdeArtifactRegistry

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Has anyone encountered this before / knows how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: where you added `apply plugin: 'idea'` and why ? Is it required to run LibGDX project ??

Comment: I've added it to "C:\Users\user\init.gradle as i see it doesn't have the idea task. but it did not help. Thanks.